# get current user WordPress return empty value

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to figure out how to get the id of the current user, but it returns me an empty string.

I'm trying to get this after logging into a function within the folder /wp-content/mu-plugins/.

This is because I am using apppresser and therefore this function requires to be put there: https://docs.apppresser.com/article/408-custom-login-redirects

The code works, but does not enter the if because it cannot get the user id.

I know that to get the id the function must be called in init, but in this case since there is another hook i don't know how to do it.

This is my code:

```
function my_appp_login_redirect() {

global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();

require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder/wp-config.php'); 
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/folder/wp-load.php'); 

add_action( 'init', function() {
$user_id = $current_user->ID;
//$user_id = get_current_user_id();
});

do_action('init');

$user_id = $current_user->ID;

$status = rcp_get_status($user_id);

//echo "<script>console.log(Stato:$member_subscription)<script>";
echo "<script>console.log(Stato:$user_id)<script>";

if($status=='expired'){ 
echo "<script>console.log('scaduto')<script>";
return array(
'title' => 'Redirect utente loggato', 
'url'   => 'redirect-utente-loggato' // page slug from your app's 
custom page
);
}
else{
echo "<script>console.log('non scaduto')<script>";
   return array(
'title' => 'Come funziona',
'url'   => 'come-funziona' // page slug from your app's custom 
page
); 
}
}
add_filter( 'appp_login_redirect', 'my_appp_login_redirect' );
return array(
'title' => 'Redirect utente loggato',
'url' => 'redirect-utente-loggato' // page slug from your app's 
custom page
 );

 add_filter( 'appp_login_redirect', 'my_appp_login_redirect' );
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the following to get the information of the logged in user:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
global $current_user;
$current_user = wp_get_current_user();
//$user_id = get_current_user_id();
});

do_action('init');

$current_user->ID;
```

Comment: I have tried and return ever an empty value. I updated the code with your suggest.

Comment: If I comment INIT functions the value returned is 0

Comment: Possibly the init add_action hook is already called before you call it in your function. You could try adding the `do_action('init')` below the add_action and set the current user in the add action. Then call the current user after the do_action.

Comment: Done what you suggest, but nothing, same results.

Comment: Ok, I tried, but with your update return an empty value.